# How to programmatically show a CompletionList in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to be able to show a `CompletionList` in a specified editor/position to the user programmatically (not based on user typing a trigger character). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original: As of today (12/12/2018), this is not possible.

Edit: Attempted to delete this post in favor of @Gama11's answer below but cannot delete accepted answers. I'm not 100% positive the `editor.action.triggerSuggest` is supported but it works.

@Gama11's response below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53804882/1574622

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this is possible by executing the `"editor.action.triggerSuggest"` command. This is the same command that gets executed when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to manually invoke completion.

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.triggerSuggest");
```

If you want to control where the popup opens, simply change the active editor + selection beforehand:

```ts
var file = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath + "/foo.txt";
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(file).then(document => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(document).then(editor => {
        editor.selection = new vscode.Selection(10, 0, 10, 0);
        vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.triggerSuggest");
    });
});
```